# Why doesn't Cyclops blast Wolverine?

Tags: marvel, x-men

When Cyclops and Jean encounter Wolverine outside of the room where he was last seen fighting Mystique, the following scene occurs:

> **Wolverine:** Hey, hey. It's me.
>
> **Cyclops:** Prove it.
>
> **Wolverine:** You're a dick.
>
> **Cyclops:** Okay.

Why does Cyclops accept this answer? After all Mystique obviously saw that the two don't care for each other after seeing Wolverine flip Cyclops off with his claw. Also, she must have heard Logan disregard a direct order from Cyclops before walking off.

Not trying to be picky or anything but after being ambushed by Toad and Mystique, I was just surprised to see Scott acting so foolish. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

**In-universe answer:** Mystique might have known they didn't like each other by observing their behavior, but the crass and abrasive answer to a reasonable question is vintage Wolverine.  Cyclops could have been wrong, but he was betting that no one trying to "blend in" would be so brazenly hostile.

Basically, even if Mystique had known they weren't friends, it's unlikely that she would have known that their core relationship was one of hostility.  When forced to prove her identity, she likely would have tried to talk him down, or appeal to his cooperative nature.  But when Wolverine responded with a flat insult, the tactic was so counter to Mystique's probable interest that it was sufficient to convince Cyclops that it wasn't Mystique.

**True answer:** the [Rule of Funny](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfFunny), and the power of Joss Whedon to punch up a script.

Comment: Joss Whedon? David Hayter right?

Comment: @kaine  Joss Whedon was brought in to punch up Hayter's script, and he added several of the most memorable lines, including "you're a dick."  He also added Storm's infamous "what happens to a toad when it's struck by lightning, the same thing that happens to everything else" line, but Whedon had intended for it to be a casual quip, and was horrified when he saw it delivered with such over-the-top intensity.

Comment: I was unaware...no wonder I actually like that movie...Thanks!

Comment: @kaine Happy to help!  :)  BTW, another little-known Joss Whedon credit: he co-wrote the original *Toy Story*, for which he got an Oscar nomination.

Comment: He also wrote most of *Speed*, but didn't get a credit due to policies.